# How to disable pagination in Prime NG?

Tags: angular, pagination, primeng

After a lot of searches, I didn't get the proper answer to disable primeng pagination.

Comment: Can you explain more your requirement? Like you want to disable the Pagination button or you want to hide the Paginator ?

Comment: Not hide, want to disable.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not directly available in PrimeNG paginator. I have used small hack to achieve it:

```
// Once data has been assigned to the table
this.data = mydataFromService;

setTimeout(()=>{
    $(".ui-paginator-element").addClass('disabled'); 
    // You can use index if you want to disable a particular button/link
}, 0);

// In some CSS file
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none; // mandatory: prevents from click event to trigger
    cursor: not-allowed; // optional: if you want cursor to indicate 'disabled'
}
```

Note:
custom class is used instead of `ui-state-disabled` as it overwrites a particular scenario.

scenario:
you are on first page - `First` or `<` indicator is by default disabled using class `ui-state-disabled`.

now once disabled if you try to enable the pagination, will have to remove 'ui-state-disabled' like this `$(".ui-paginator-element").removeClass('disabled');`

This will enable the `First` or `<` element which is wrong. So its better to use custom class instead.

Comment: With `ui-state-disabled`, only the links look like disabled but they are actually not.They are still clickable and even new data loads. Any other solution tried?

Comment: We can add another class and add some css property like 
.someClass{
pointer-event:disabled;
cursor:cursor: not-allowed;
}

$(".ui-paginator-element").addClass('someClass');

Comment: `cursor: not-allowed;` was not required for me but `pointer-events:none;` worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please accept the answer this might help someone too. @KunalDethe

Comment: I have edited your latest answer with some elaborations, please check. Revert on it and will accept the updated answer. Thanks.